# Looping through a JSON to group values by key

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file containing a bunch of songs with the associated song lines, verse number etc. My goal is to print each distinct verse. I'm having difficulty constructing a loop that works. Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
[{ "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"},
 { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}]
```

In this JSON there are 5 verses total.

1. Song 1, Verse 1: "Mato Joe Tsinki" / "Chiti Chiti"
2. Song 1, Verse 2: "Raro Raro" / "Shinan Kibi" / "Bewa Bewa"
3. Song 2, Verse 1: "Ramo Kano"
4. Song 2, Verse 2: "Choro Choro"
5. Song 3, Verse 1: "Pisha Pisha"

I've written the following which successfully prints the 1st verse of every song but not subsequent verses.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var colors = require('colors');
fs.readFile('stackoverflow.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
data = JSON.parse(data); 

for(var i in data) { 
    var item = data[i];
    // construct string song:verse:line
    var lineIndex = item.song   
    lineIndex += ":"+item.verse
    lineIndex += ":"+item.lineNum

    var numSongs = 20
    var songNum = 1
    var verseNum = 1
    var lineNum = 1
    // console.log(verseNum)

        while(item.song <= numSongs && item.verse == verseNum)
        {       
            console.log(lineIndex.green + ' ' + item.line);
            verseNum++;
        }
}
});
```

Updated to demonstrate desired output a console log:

Song 1 Verse 1:
"Mato Joe Tsinki"
"Chiti Chiti"

Song 1 Verse 2:
"Raro Raro"
"Shinan Kibi"
"Bewa Bewa"

Song 2 Verse 1:
....

Comment: Hi Dave, before I type up an answer, do you have access to the lodash library (or underscore) in your project? Also are you able to use ecmascript 6?

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: I am ok using other libraries like lodash. Thanks for quick replies.

Comment: Adiga, grouping based on verse.

Comment: Have updated question with desired output. Thanks for responses.

Comment: @Dave What is that, exactly? An array of strings? Multiple `console.log()`s? One long string with line breaks? That doesn't really make it any clearer. The desired output should be represented as *code*, much like your input array.

Comment: Desired output is multiple console logs (updated question also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the verses and create an accumulator object with each unique combination of `song` and `verse` as it's `key`s. And, then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the final output. This creates an array of `lines` for each combo of `song` and `verse`:

```js
var verses = 
[{ "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"},
 { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}]
 
 
 const merged = verses.reduce((acc, { song, verse, line }) => {
  const key = `${song}-${verse}`
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {song, verse, lines: []};
  acc[key]["lines"].push(line);
  return acc
 }, {})
 
 const output = Object.values(merged)
 
 console.log(output)
```

If you want the `lines` separated by a `/`, then use a string property and concatenate each `line`:

```js
var verses = 
[{ "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"},
 { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}]
 
 
 const merged = verses.reduce((acc, { song, verse, line }) => {
  const key = `${song}-${verse}`;
  
  if(acc[key])
    acc[key]["lines"] += " / " + line;
  else
    acc[key] = {song, verse, lines: line};
    
  return acc
 }, {})
 
 const output = Object.values(merged)
 
 console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `while` and `for`, consider using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

As an array of `lines` with `line` and `lineNum`:

```js
var arr = [{ "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"}, { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"}, { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"}, { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}];
 
let result = arr.reduce((out, i) => {
    let found = out.find(s => s.song === i.song && s.verse === i.verse);
    let {line, lineNum, ...newSong} = i;
    let {song, verse, ...newLine} = i;
    
    found 
      ? found.lines.push(newLine)
      : out.push({...newSong, lines: [newLine]});
      
    return out;
  }, []);
   
console.log(result);
```

Comma-separated:

```js
var arr = [{ "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"}, { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"}, { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"}, { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"}, { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}];
 
let result = arr.reduce((out, i) => {
    var found = out.find(s => s.song === i.song && s.verse === i.verse);
    
    found 
      ? found.line += ", " + i.line  //Song found - combine the lines
      : out.push(i);                 //Song not found - add it as new item

    return out;
  }, []);
   
console.log(result);
```

`reduce()` will loop through each song in the array to build a collection. If it finds the same song and verse in the collection already, it adds the lines together. If not, it adds the entire song to the collection.

That said, you haven't clearly defined what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I updated the question with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another version that uses first [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to group the lines by `song` and `verses` taking care of put they in order on an array first (just in case the original array is not ordered). Then we use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get your expected output:

```js
let input = [
 { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Chiti chiti"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Mato Joe Tsinki"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Raro Raro"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 3, "line": "Bewa bewa"},
 { "song": 1, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 2, "line": "Shinan Kibi"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Ramo Kano"},
 { "song": 2, "verse": 2, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Choro Choro"},
 { "song": 3, "verse": 1, "lineNum": 1, "line": "Pisha Pisha"}
];

let verses = {};

input.forEach(o =>
{
    let k = `${o.song}_${o.verse}`;
    verses[k] = verses[k] || {song: o.song, verse: o.verse};
    verses[k]["lines"] = verses[k]["lines"] || [];
    verses[k]["lines"][o.lineNum] = o.line;
});

let res = Object.values(verses).map(
    o => `song ${o.song}, verse ${o.verse}, lines: ${o.lines.filter(Boolean).join(" / ")}`
);

console.log(res);
```